# Add values to a data frame column at a specific row number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `df` call which looks like:

```
                  A          B             C
Date            
02/02/2007  14.8966   0.289371   0.009984836
05/02/2007  14.8719   0.288368  -0.001659473
06/02/2007  14.9295   0.279869   0.003865595
07/02/2007  15.0035   0.283038   0.004944386
08/02/2007  15.0528   0.277092   0.003280513
09/02/2007  14.7733   0.28663   -0.018742523
12/02/2007  14.6911   0.286458  -0.005579629
13/02/2007  14.996    0.275362   0.020541631
14/02/2007  15.5731   0.253263   0.037761568
```

I have a for loop in which I am using to manipulate a timeseries.  The result is a variable called `testValue` that I would like to add to `df` in a new column called `'D'` at the row reference `endpoint` (endpoint is a sequentially increasing integer).

```
for i in range(buildRange,len(pair_data)-calcRange+1):
    startpoint=i
    endpoint = startpoint+calcRange
    Calc_df=df[startpoint:endpoint].copy()
    Calc_df['C']=Calc_df.iloc[-1, Calc_df.columns.get_loc('A')]-Calc_df['B']
    testValue= sum(x for x in Calc_df["C"] if x > 0)
    
    df.loc[endpoint, 'D'] = testValue
```

So over the course of the loop column 'D' will build up with testValue values.  Is it possible to reference a row in a dataframe and not the index? At the moment using `df.loc[endpoint, 'D'] = testValue`  creates a new column `'D'` but adds the data to the bottom of the data-frame and not to the correct row. (I think it's because endpoint is an integer and the index is date so it can't find the reference so creates a new one at the bottom of the data frame).

So for example if endpoint started at 4 the desired output to look like:

```
              A          B             C             D
Date            
02/02/2007  14.8966   0.289371   0.009984836
05/02/2007  14.8719   0.288368  -0.001659473
06/02/2007  14.9295   0.279869   0.003865595
07/02/2007  15.0035   0.283038   0.004944386    1.36535
08/02/2007  15.0528   0.277092   0.003280513    0.27821
09/02/2007  14.7733   0.28663   -0.018742523    0.25356
12/02/2007  14.6911   0.286458  -0.005579629    2780435
13/02/2007  14.996    0.275362   0.020541631    0.36635
14/02/2007  15.5731   0.253263   0.037761568    0.25368
        :                            :
31/12/2007  15.9364   0.763263   0.047435768    0.24663
```

(Values in column 4 are just for illustrative purposes and would note correct if the code was run).

Comment: Looks like some sort of `rolling`. I can't really tell what you're trying to do without specific data. One thing for sure is that your data is indexed by `Date` but you seem to update with `df.loc[endpoint, 'D']` where `endpoint` is an integer. Your code wouldn't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang - is there a way to reference a row and not a row index in the dataframe?

Comment: Quick reminder about the expectation on Stack Overflow for technical writing. Appreciations, thanks, gratitude, greetings, signatures etc are best omitted.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to verify what you are trying to do. From your code, this is what I guess:

```
df['D'] = (df['A'].shift()       # correspond to `Calc_df.iloc[-1, Calc_df.columns.get_loc('A')]`
            .sub( df['B'])       # subtract df['B']
            .mul(df['C'].gt(0))  # only look at `df['C']>0`
            .rolling(4).sum()    # sum the last 4 occurrences
          )
```

Output:

```
                  A         B         C          D
Date                                              
02/02/2007  14.8966  0.289371  0.009985        NaN
05/02/2007  14.8719  0.288368 -0.001659        NaN
06/02/2007  14.9295  0.279869  0.003866        NaN
07/02/2007  15.0035  0.283038  0.004944        NaN
08/02/2007  15.0528  0.277092  0.003281  43.964901
09/02/2007  14.7733  0.286630 -0.018743  43.964901
12/02/2007  14.6911  0.286458 -0.005580  29.372870
13/02/2007  14.9960  0.275362  0.020542  29.142146
14/02/2007  15.5731  0.253263  0.037762  29.158475
```